# Positioning my form fields onto an image

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/danilopena/fVh23/5/

That is a link to the HTML/CSS I have been working on. For some reason, when I try to position the text of the image, the text disappears? Is it going behind the image or something? Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: What do you recommend doing exactly?

Comment: You are using `margin` for the wrong purpose. Use a `background-image` CSS attribute instead of displaying an image and trying to overlay it.

Comment: So, in CSS, would it be... background: url(http://i1078.photobucket.com/albums/w500/DaniloPena/main_form.png);

Comment: Yep. Add that to your `main` element. I'd put quotes around the URL as well. To position the content properly, use `padding-top` to clear the area below the image's text.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you have to keep the image in the foreground you might use `z-index:-1;` to push something to the back. Higher values will bring it to the front; default is 1.